# How to show that the row vectors of a special unitary group of degree 2 form an orthonormal basis?

Tags: complex-numbers, orthonormal

I'm studying about special unitary groups and came across a problem that I'm having trouble with.

> If we define a special unitary group of degree $2$ as:
>
> $$\text{SU}(2) = \left\{ \begin{bmatrix}\phantom{-}a & b \\ - \bar{b} & \bar{a} \end{bmatrix} : a\bar{a} + b\bar{b} = 1 \right\}$$
>
> If the inner product of two complex vectors $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$ is defined as:
>
> $$\sum_{i} a_i \bar{b}_i$$
>
> then show that the row vectors form an orthonormal basis.

I first started with the fact that by definition if a set of vectors form an orthonormal basis then:

1. They are orthogonal to each other.
2. They have magnitudes of $1$.
3. They are linearly independent.

I was able to easily show the first condition by:

$$
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix} a \\ b \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix}-\bar{b} \\ \phantom{-} \bar{a}\end{bmatrix} & = a \overline{(-\bar{b})} + b\overline{(\bar{a})} \\
& = -ab + ba \\
& = 0
\end{align}
$$

How do I progress with the second and third? I've tried something like:

$$
\left\Vert \begin{bmatrix}a \\ b \end{bmatrix}  \right\Vert^2 = a^2 + b^2
$$

but I don't know how to progress from here.

Comment: I assume you want to prove that the rows are an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb C$?

Comment: The exercise question doesn't specify, but I believe it's safe to assume so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if $[a,b]$ is a row of such a matrix then

$$\|[a,b]\|^2 = [a,b] \cdot [a,b] = a\bar{a}+b\bar{b} = 1 $$

As for linear independence, if
$$v=\lambda[a,b] + \mu[-\bar{b},\bar{a}]=0$$
then use that $v\cdot[a,b]=0\cdot[a,b]=0$ to deduce $\lambda=0$:

$$0=v\cdot[a,b] = \lambda([a,b]\cdot[a,b]) + \mu([-\bar{b},\bar{a}]\cdot[a,b]) = \lambda$$

Similarly, $\mu=0$.

Comment: How did you get the absolute squares for the magnitude? There wasn't anything specific about the inner product or norm in the exercise question.

Comment: I've edited the answer: when there's an inner product, we can define a modulus: $\|[a,b]\| = \sqrt{[a,b] \cdot [a,b]}$